# show H is closed under *

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $*$ is an associative binary operation on a set $S$. Let $H=\{a \in S|a*x=x*a, \forall x \in S\}$. Show that $H$ is closed under $*$  (We think of H as consisting of all elements of $S$ that commute with every element in $S$)

if I understand the question correctly, its looking for me to show $a*(x_1*x_2)=(a*x_1)*x_2 = x_2 * (x_1*a)=(x_2*x_1)*a$ or something of the sort?

Comment: you want to show if $a_1\in H$ and $a_2\in H$ then $a*b\in H$. To do this you have to prove $(a_1*a_2)x=x(a_1*a_2)$ for any $x\in H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x*(a_1*a_2)=(x*a_1)*a_2=(a_1*x)*a_2=a_1*(x*a_2)=a_1*(a_2*x)=(a_1*a_2)*x$

Comment: ah okay, that makes more sense. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are proving that the center of a group is a subgroup of the group. The definition of $H$ you gave is really more like $Z(S,*)$, the center of S endowed with a group operation, where $Z$ denotes the center of a group. All you need to know will be easily found here, including the proof:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28group_theory%29

The important part (the closure) is:

"If x and y are in Z(G), then (xy)g = x(yg) = x(gy) = (xg)y = (gx)y = g(xy) for each $g \in G$, and so xy is in Z(G) as well (i.e., Z(G) exhibits closure)"

Comment: $S$ might not be a group.

Comment: we just started so not quite there yet but thank you. It is in our chapter about groups but doesn't say whether it is a group or not.

Comment: @JorgeFernández totally dig that but thought it might help if he had something to Google... and I don't think the argument relies on anything group-theoretic, just the associativity and commutativity of $*$

Comment: fine, you convinced me, +1